# Adjust size Container?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter, I'm trying to change size of a container, but it not change even i change `height:150` and `width=150`, I just want green screen show about 1/5 screen, but i really don't know how to fix this. I don't understand why, when changing the height and width of the Container, nothing will change

here is code

```
return Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
      child: new MaterialApp(
        title: "Sample",
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Container(
          height: 150.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.green,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
              )),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                top: 150,
                left: 0,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SvgPicture.asset(
                      user,
                      width: 60,
                      height: 60,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Welcome back, $username",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontFamily: fontRegular,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(width: 1.5, color: Colors.black),
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(230, 230, 230, 1),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          SvgPicture.asset(
                            "assert\\dollar.svg",
                            height: 25,
                            width: 25,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            '$coinValue',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                decoration: TextDecoration.none),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 13,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here is result

[image: Result]

i just want something like this

[image: result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your code as below:

```
home: Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        height: 150.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Text(
              "Welcome back",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                //fontFamily: fontRegular,
                decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(width: 1.5, color: Colors.black),
                color: Color.fromRGBO(230, 230, 230, 1),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'dsfsfsf',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.none),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 13,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: It also work!! Thank you so much, but when we use Positioned , and when to use other?

Answer (score 2):

hope this helps you:

Add Scaffold around the inner container (the one with height 150 )... and you don't need the stack and positioned(the content won't show up if you don't remove them):

```
MaterialApp(
      title: "Sample",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          height: 150.0,
          decoration: ...
```

Comment: Will I rewrite from "Stack"  and later on? because Positioned as far as I know, it needs a stack, i'm very new to flutter, hope you help me

Comment: It work!!!!! Thank you so much, but why it work with Scafford, i don't understand

Comment: Hi.. Flutter is big and has really nice thing to learn that shall help you in your code(With practice and reading the documentation this will be piece of a cake for you) 

Small notes from me to help you with this code and in your journey:
1- for spacing use padding and alignment instead of using stack and positioned(stack and positioned better to be used when you want things over each other)

2- I am sure also you get many blue lines under your code (if you use VSCode) hover over them with your mouse and it will tell you how to make that line better.

Comment: 3- You don't need to use the keyword 'new' any more.
4- Use SafeArea around the widget that you want it to be under the phone top bar.
5- if you ever face a problem that the widgets out of the screen and you get yellow things and says some thing about pixels use FittedBox
6- Learn and practice those widgets and there attributes , they will help you to build general understanding for  widgets: 
Row, Column, padding, Container, Scaffold,and SizedBox.

Comment: "Scaffold it is mainly responsible for creating a base to the app screen on which the child widgets hold on and render on the screen" https://www.javatpoint.com/flutter-scaffold

Comment: thank you so much, i very appreciate these imformation

Answer (score 1):

You have the `Stack` widget inside your `Container` widget. That is why it is taking the whole screen. Try removing the `Stack` widget.

```
return Container(
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
  child: new MaterialApp(
    title: "Sample",
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Container(
      height: 150.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.green,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
          )),
      child: Positioned(
            top: 150,
            left: 0,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                SvgPicture.asset(
                  user,
                  width: 60,
                  height: 60,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Welcome back, $username",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontFamily: fontRegular,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(width: 1.5, color: Colors.black),
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(230, 230, 230, 1),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      SvgPicture.asset(
                        "assert\\dollar.svg",
                        height: 25,
                        width: 25,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '$coinValue',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            decoration: TextDecoration.none),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 13,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: First thank you for answering my question, but after I remove the Stack there is an error "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget"

Answer (score 1):

Do as follows

```
  Container(
  height: 150,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.green,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20))),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      CircleAvatar(
        radius: 30.0,
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://via.placeholder.com/150'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      Expanded(child:Text("Hey there, Welcome back LQK!")),
       Container(
         width:100,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(width: 1.5, color: Colors.black),
            color: Color.fromRGBO(230, 230, 230, 1),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.search) //put your desired icon here 
            ],
          ),
        ),
    ],
  )
```